# How to request list of users with GONG API?

Tags: python, api

https://app.gong.io/settings/api/documentation#overview

```
import base64

auth = <my_pass>
auth2 = auth.encode('ascii')
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(auth2)

headers = {"Authorization" : "base64_bytes"}

response = requests.get("https://api.gong.io/v2/users",headers)
print(response)
```

In the Gong API Page (you must be a technical administrator in Gong), click "Create" to receive an Access Key and an Access Key Secret.
Use the Basic Authorization HTTP header (as per RFC) to access the Public API as shown below:
Authorization: Basic 
To create the basic token, combine the Access Key and the Access Key Secret with colon (:) and then encode in Base64 as following:
Base64( : )

Comment: I hope thats not your real pass.

Comment: ummm... isn't supposed to be add "Basic"  as per documentation? 

Use the Basic Authorization HTTP header (as per RFC) to access the Public API as shown below:
Authorization: Basic <token>

headers = {"Authorization" : f"Basic {base64_bytes}"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go: keep it simple :-)

```
import requests 

#This sets up the https connection
url  = "https://api.gong.io/v2/users"

access_key = <access_key>
secret_key = <secret_key>


r = requests.get(url, auth=(access_key,secret_key))
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Hi @hnandarusdy, Do you have any projects using gongs API with python?

Comment: yeap... although just started as well and the project is still on going :-)

Comment: Thats cool, would love to see your progress if you have anything publicly available :)